# Codigo de Barras Java

Tags: java

Como fazer uma validação de codigo de barras em Java ?
Um aplicativo em Java que simule um leitor de código de barras. O programa solicita ao usuário a digitação dos 13 dígitos do código de um determinado produto e retorna a seguir a informação indicando que o código é válido ou não.
Considere que o usuário poderá lançar quantos códigos de produtos ele desejar.

Comment: [Conheço está library](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) para Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todo último número de código de barras seria o resultado de uma conta com os outros números anteriores. Sendo assim armazene os 13 , 12 ou 11 dígitos em um vetor usando strings e depois converta eles em inteiros.

Após isso, faça todos números em posições ímpares * 1 e números em posições pares * 1 (ou seja ele mesmo, após isso, some todos os resultados, armazene esse resultado em outra variável e divida por 10, (caso use double passe para inteiro).

Soma esse resultado com 1 e depois multiplique por 10, após isso tudo, subtraia o resultado armazenado com esse último resultado e "voilà", se o último número bater com  a conta então esse código de barras é correto se não ele é incorreto.

```
int i = 0;
    double code[] = new double[13];
    double total = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < 12;i++)
    {
        codigo_barra += cody[i];  

        code[i] = Integer.parseInt(cody[i]);


            if(i%2== 0)
            {
                code[i] *= 3;                  
            }          


       total += code[i];
    }   

    double t = total;
    total /= 10;
    int to = (int)total;

    to += 1;
    to *=10; 
    to -= t;


    if(to == code[13])
    {
        valida = "Codigo Correto";            
    }
    else
    {
        valida = "Codigo Incorreto";
    }

    System.out.println("Resultado: "+to);
```